# RegExMatch backreference group with literal string

Tags: regex

I can't figure out how to make a back reference pass a group of string instead of only 1, hard for me to explain but I hope you can understand.

This is what I have, XX([^---]+?)XX

It WILL match 12345XX text XX54321

It will NOT match 12345XX -text- XX54321

the problem lies here > ([^---]+?) <

I can't figure out how to make it match 3 dashes instead of 1.

I would appreciate any help. =)

Comment: Use negative lookahead: `(?!---)`

Comment: square brackets match any of the items contained, but only once.  using `[^---]` is equivalent to using `[^-]`. as @hjpotter92 mentioned, a negative lookahead is what you need.  remember to follow it with a matching item, for example `((?!---).)+`

Comment: Thanks wolffer that's what I was looking for. =P

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to come up with a regex for you, this match a simple string, a string within dash and all dashes

**Regex**

```
(?:XX\s?)([\w-]+)(?:\sXX)
```

**Test string**

> 12345XX text XX54321
>
> 12345XX -text- XX54321
>
> 12345XX --- XX54321

**Result**

MATCH 1

1. [8-12]  `text`

MATCH 2

1. [29-35] `-text-`

MATCH 3

1. [52-55] `---`

try [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/aU7oQ1/1)

---

**SET 2**

**Regex**

```
(?:XX\s?[^\w]*)([\w]+)(?:[^\w]*\sXX)
```

**Test string**

> 12345XX text XX54321
>
> 12345XX -text- XX54321
>
> 12345XX ---test--- XX54321

**Result**

MATCH 1

1. [8-12]  `text`

MATCH 2

1. [30-34] `text`

MATCH 3

1. [55-59] `test`

try [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/aU7oQ1/3)

Note: test string and regex are based on assumptions, we can adjust as needed